# Grouped random sample MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, random

Lets say that I want to randomly sample a database with `id` of the following form

```
id 
A    
A
A
B
C
C
D
D
E
F
```

Instead of doing a completely random sample how would I sample 50% of the distinct groups. The difference is that a random sample would give me half of all of the records while a grouped sample would give me half of all of the distinct `ids`.

This is necessary because I would not want to partially sample an `id`. If an `A` is selected then all 3 `A`s should be included in this kind of grouped random sample.

Lets say for example the group set {`A`,`B`,`C`} was randomly selected. The query would produce the following

```
id
A
A
A
B
C
C
```

Comment: If you had 99 A's 99 B's and 1 each of C and D would you be happy with a sample just containing 2 rows?

Comment: @MartinSmith if one A was chosen and one C was chose the result would have 100 rows. 99As and 1C

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't be a guaranteed result. You might get 2 rows, or 198 using the logic as requested. C and D are weighted equally to A and B.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that is exactly would I would like. 1. Randomly select half of the distinct groups. 2. Return all of the records for those selected distinct groups. The result could very well be 2 rows (if C and D), or 198 rows if (A and B), this is of course using your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  [id] IN (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT [id]
                FROM   YourTable
                GROUP  BY [id]
                ORDER  BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))
```

Comment: If there is no aggregation such as a `sum()` will the `group by` be selecting distinct groups?

Comment: yes. Just use `SELECT [id]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [id]` to see this

Comment: Also, why order by `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) `

Comment: Because you want a random sampling. So the distinct ids are identified and then placed in a random order with only the top 50 % after re-ordering retained.

Comment: I have been getting slow results with `ORDER  BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)` are there faster options?

Comment: 100 millionish IDs and probably .5 billion rows total.